# Copyarifacts plugin not able to find Multibranch pipeline projects

Tags: jenkins

I installed copyartifacts plugin in Jenkins. I created two projects one is freestyle or maven project and another one is multibranch pipeline project.

But in freestyle or maven project I'm not ale to search or discover projects under copy artifacts from another project.(Projects are not populated under Copyartifacts from another project)

Copyartifacts issue with multibranch pipeline:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copying an artifact from a Multibranch Pipeline job to a freestyle job works fine for me.  Are you sure you're using the correct job name?  For a Multibranch Pipeline job, you need to use the full job name, since a Multibranch Pipeline project creates nested folders for the individual jobs.  For instance, to copy an artifact from the master branch of the "my-repo" repository in the "My Project" Multibranch project, you would need to use the full name of the job which would be something like "MP/my-repo/master".